# Unity 5 - Cloth Constraints

Tags: unity, cloth

I'm trying out the new Version of Unity 3D (5.0.0.4f) and figure out whats new, whats possible now. My experience with Unity 4 free is also just a little. Anyway I work with the "new" cloth component and have some general questions to different funkctions. The documentation brought no knowledge to me. So I would be thankful if one of you could explain me the different points in an accessible way.

First question touchs the constraints. When I edit the contraints (of a plane for example), there are two options to activate. What are the differents between "Max Distance" and "Surface penetration". "max Distance" is clear to me but i don't know what the second option does.

Seceond question: I have an tablecloth positioned over a sphere. In playmode when i move the sphere up and the tablecloth react correctly. But the sphere ist temporaliry visible trough the cloth. Its look like a graphicbug then, but ist there a way to prevent this?

So I hope my questions a clear enough to understand. Thanks a lot for your educational effort.

Comment: have you tried adding a collider to the sphere that is a little bigger than the sphere so the coloth wont actually colide with the sphere itself?